# Showing a Lipschitz transformation maps a set of measure zero to a set of measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a Lipschitz transformation. that is, 
$$\exists C<\infty:|T(x)-T(y)|\leq C|x-y|$$
for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

and now I want to show that if $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2,\mu(E)=0$, then $\mu(T(E))=0$ where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

here's what I tired:

since $\mu(E)=0$, there exists a countable collection of nonoverlapping, open, **square** intervals $\{I_k\}$ s.t. $E\subseteq \cup I_k$, $\sum\mu(I_k)<\epsilon$, for any given $\epsilon>0$ by the definition of the Lebesgue measure: $$\mu(E)=\inf\{\sum\nu(I_k):E\subseteq\cup I_k,\{I_k\}\text{ is a countable collection of nonoverlapping open intervals}\}$$ where $\nu(I_k)$ is the "area" of an interval $I_k=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:a_1< x< b_1, a_2< y< b_2\}$: $\nu(I_k)=(b_2-a_2)(b_1-a_1)=\mu(I_k)$.

we can choose the intervals to be square since we can cut any rectangle into a countable collection of many nonoverlapping square pieces.

and since if $a\in T(\cup I_k)$, then there is $k_0$ s.t. $a\in T(I_{k_0})$, so we have $T(\cup I_k)\subseteq \cup T(I_k)$ and thus $\mu(T(E))\leq \mu(T(\cup I_k))\leq \sum\mu(T(I_k))$.

and now we define a disk $D_k$ whose diameter is of $I_k$'s and containing $I_k$: $D_k=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^2:|z-(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2},\frac{b_2-b_1}{2})|\leq\frac{diam(I_k)}{2}\}$. I used the definition of $I_k$ above.

and by the Lipschitz condition, if $x,y\in D_k$, then $|T(x)-T(y)|\leq C|x-y|$, thus $diam(T(D_k))\leq C\cdot diam(D_k)=C\cdot diam(I_k)$.

and since each $I_k$ is square, $b_2-a_2=b_1-a_1=c$, thus $diam(I_k)^2=(b_2-a_2)^2+(b_1-a_1)^2=2c^2=2\mu(I_k)$

thus, $\mu(T(E))\leq \sum\mu(T(I_k)) \leq \sum \mu(T(D_k)) \leq \sum \frac{\pi}{2}diam(T(D_k))^2\leq\sum\frac{\pi}{2}C^2\cdot diam(D_k)^2=\sum\frac{\pi C^2}{2}diam(I_k)^2=\sum\frac{\pi C^2}{2}\cdot 2\mu(I_k)=\pi C^2\sum\mu(I_k)<\pi C^2\epsilon$

so I conclude $\mu(T(E))=0$.

I was trying to do as rigorous as I can, but I'm not sure if I can choose the **square** intervals. as I wrote, since we can partition any rectangles into squares, it seems fine, but they are **open** intervals. so they don't have boundaries, it means if we cut a rectangle then the lines we cut along will not be included.

and if I choose arbitrary rectangle intervals, then there can be very thin rectangles so that they have long diameter but small area. so if there are the ones with positive diameter and small area converging to $0$, I can't use my argument.

so the question is, can I choose square intervals like above? then how do I deal with the lines I cut? if we can't, how do I show this with general intervals?

thank you for reading this long question.

Comment: Why do you use open squares instead of open disks? I'd say the proof would be much simpler with the latter.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy because of the definition of the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: if I use open disks then I have to show the Lebesgue measure and the measure with open disks are the same, right?

Comment: What definition of Lebesgue measure are you using?

Comment: @zhw. I wrote it in my question. $\mu(E)$.

Comment: @zhw. see line 9.

Comment: So $\mu(E) = \inf \sum \mu (I_k),$ where $E \subset \cup I_k,$ and each $I_k$ is an open square?

Comment: no, the definition doesn't include the square part.

Comment: You say "non overlapping" above. That can fail. But you don't need nonoverlapping squares anyway.

Comment: @zhw. the notion of 'nonoverlapping' is the one making me confused I guess. I don't know the difference of 'nonoverlapping' and 'disjoint'. I get that we don't need nonoverlapping squares. but when you measure some set, and if you need more than one interval, they must nonoverlap from the definition, and I see the same 'crack' there. the measure of crack is zero, but the point is because of it we can't cover the target with nonoverlapping intervals. how do we solve it?

Comment: I've never seen "non overlapping" as part of the definition. It's impossible to cover the open unit disc with nonoverlapping open rectangles for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof can be shortened considerably. Here are two exercises that should help.

1. If $R$ is an open rectangle, then there are finitely many open squares $S_1, \dots, S_n$ such that $R\subset \cup S_k$ and $\sum \mu (S_k) < 2\mu (R).$
2. Let $T$ be the Lipschitz map you mention (with Lipschitz constant $C$). For $a\in \mathbb R^2$ and $l>0,$ let $S(a,l)$ denote the open square with center $a$ and side length $l.$ Then $T(S(a,l)) \subset S(T(a),\sqrt 2 C l).$